# Call old launcher (Android HOME)

Tags: android

I have an application marked as default by checkbox...

With these settings in the manifest:

`<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />`

from my application, i need call the Home of Android, **not** my default app.

Answer (score 0):

You can start an activity using its package and class names rather than the category, but the trick here is you need to know what package/class to start. You can't safely make an assumption of what package/class to start on a generic device, however you can use the PackageManager to enumerate through everything the device has; just look for something else with an android.intent.category.HOME category and start it. If there are more than one alternatives, you'll need to decide how to proceed.

Comment: I don't have a code sample handy, however the http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html has a `getInstalledPackages()` method to get all packages for you in a `List` of `PackageInfo` to get started with. The Android documentation will describe the many classes to eventually lead you to this.